# Using Outlook Interop

Tags: asp.net, outlook, interop

I have written a DLL that creates meeting requests using Outlook Interop.  This all works hunky-dory on my machine.

Problem is, when I run it on the server (which doesn't have Outlook installed), it fails with a COM error.  I have copied the DLLs into the `bin` directory, but still no joy.  Can anyone help?

Comment: So you're using an interop library for an application where the application isn't even installed? What's the point of using an interop then? You should be looking at IMAP/Exchange libraries if you want to interface with email without Outlook installed.

Comment: I don't get it... You want to create meeting requests in Outlook without Outlook installed? Anyway, using the interop functionality of the MS Office is not the MS Office itself. It's normal to not work

Comment: @BradChristie, the poster doesn't understand "Outlook Interop". Help them, don't criticize them.

Comment: @mihail, the poster doesn't understand "Outlook Interop". Help them, don't criticize them.

Comment: @BradChristie: If the user has Outlook installed on their machine, and they view the webpage, would the Interop stuff work then?

Comment: @AMissico: Unfortunately tone is poorly conveyed over the internet; my intent was not to criticize but to motivate a thought process. Regardless, I did follow-up with IMAP/Exchange reference which was meant to assist.

Comment: @Neil: No, software on the client's machine cannot be interfaced with by visiting a website [exceptions withheld]. If you're looking to manage email from a server you either need to write an application that establishes its own connection to the email server on the user's behalf, or use a separate email application that works on its own behalf but communicates with the intended recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Microsoft Exchange Web Services, specifically *Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS) Managed API 1.1*, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877071(v=exchg.140).aspx.

This gives you nearly all the functionality of *Outlook* without requiring that *Outlook* be installed. In addition, deployment is a one (or two) assemblies.